# How to Display child product image for configurable product in Magento2?

Tags: configurable-product, magento2.2, image

I want to display child product image (which has lowest price) as a configurable product image. So if I go to configurable product view page then by default lowest price product image will display?

Can anyone help me in this? I am struggling a lot in this.

Comment: You probably also want the least expensive product selected by default as well, correct?

Comment: yes, I want to select them also.